# Upper bound for $ \sum_{p\leq x} a(p)p^{it} $

Tags: nt.number-theory, exponential-sums

The Vinogradov-Korobov zero-free region for the Riemann Zeta-function would give us an upper bound for $ \sum_{p\leq x} p^{it} $.

Now my question is, what would be the corresponding upper bound for the sum $ \sum_{p\leq x} a(p)p^{it} $, where $a(n)$  is the characteristic function of some fairly manageable subset of the natural numbers which contains many primes. The result may be expressed in a form involving (the summatory function of) $a(n)$. It may not be as sharp as the original bound on $\sum_{p\leq x}p^{it}$.

There may not be a corresponding $L$-function for the sum in question.

Comment: Use partial summation

Comment: Well... How? And what does that give?